# React-Native and Intl polyfill required on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, intl, react-intl

I recently updated my Android Studio and many components/sdk and since then React-Intl complains about `intl` library missing, even though it was working fine before.

I have installed the `intl` polyfill and I import it at the very top of my main file `App.js`. I also import the `localeData` from `react-intl` and add it. Then, I render my view within the `IntlProvider` specifying the `locale` with no messages (I only use `FormattedNumber` for now)

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
import 'intl';
import { IntlProvider, FormattedNumber, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';

addLocaleData(en);

[...]

render() {
    return (
        <IntlProvider locale="en">
            <Text>
                <FormattedNumber value={123} />
            </Text>
        </IntlProvider>
    )
}
```

I get the following error:

> [React Intl] Error formatting number. ReferenceError: No locale data
>   has been provided for this object yet.

[image]

I don't understand what's going on. Anyone encounter the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Instead of importing locale-data from `react-intl`, I have resolved the issue importing the polyfill and the locale data from `intl`

Install `intl`

```
npm install intl
```

Add this at the very top of your app:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: Thank you for saving whole my life.

Comment: And how do you do the addLocaleData part? Just ignore it? or import es from 'int/locale-data/jsonp/es' ?

Comment: What if we don't know the locale in advance? e.g. I'd like `Intl` to behave depending on the phone language.

Comment: @kunambi I gave up on that solution.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu did you find a workaround? It is pretty annoying we have to do so much work to display an amount as a function of a locale.

Comment: @pors unfortunately not. Intl apparently just doesn't play well with RN when language isn't known in advance.

Comment: Beware that this lib is discontinued, and its last update was on 2016

Answer (score 15):

### Modifying the "build.gradle"

On android, you can modify the "build.gradle" file inside  /android/app/build.gradle. Remember, it is NOT the file in  /android/app/gradle/build.gradle.

then, go to the sited file and search for:

```
      /**
     * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
     *
     * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
     * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
     *
     * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
     * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
     * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
     * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
     */
     def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
```

now, modify the last line, or simply comment it out and copy and paste the similar one above. And the result will be this:

```
      /**
     * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
     *
     * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
     * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
     *
     * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
     * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
     * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
     * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
     */
     //def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
     def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much, i solved my problem finally :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This should be the correct answer for 2022.
This solution is tested for `"react-native": "0.61.5"` and it's working great!

Answer (score 9):

Heads up, this works now with just doing the `import 'intl';` at the top and still loading the locale-data from `react-intl`. Using the following versions:

```
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"react-intl": "^2.2.2",
```

Answer (score 7):

Update to React Native 0.65 or newer

Finally "intl" is now included in Hermes, which comes with React Native 0.65 or newr - [More in React Native Blog](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/08/17/version-065)

Comment: Do you have any tips/pointers on how to use it? Just calling `Intl.DateTimeFormat` doesn't seem to work. I'm on RN68 with Hermes 0.11.0. Do I need to import something? I checked the Blog but wasn't able to make sense of it.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester, have you already tried this lib? https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-time-format-timezone

Comment: @ThomazCapra, I have not. Thanks for pointing it out. Do you have good experiences with it?

Comment: Yes I have, since hermes still don't have polyfill for all functions, you can use this library. Be careful with your bundle size, it can increase in 1MB